# Java Gameboard and Glider Homework (Need help shortening)

Tags: java

My homework is to

- Create a two dimensional array of char to represent a gameboard
- Write a glider to the game board starting at location [2][2] of the board
- Display the gameboard

I came up with below, how do I condense it?

```
public class HW8 {

 public static void main(String[] args)
   {

     char [][] gameBoard = new char[20][20];   



          int x = 0;
          int y = 0;
          char[][] a = new char[x][y];


          char[][] gliderArrays = glider(a);
          for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++)
          {
             for (int c = 0; c < a[0].length; c++)
             {
                gliderArrays[r][c] = a[r][c];

             }
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < gliderArrays.length; i++)
          {
             for (int j = 0; j < gliderArrays[0].length; j++)
             {
                gameBoard[i][j] = gliderArrays[i][j];
                gameBoard[2][2] = gliderArrays[i][j];
             }
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard[0].length; j++) {
             System.out.print(gameBoard[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();

          }
       }

       //Create the glider 2D array
       public static char[][] glider(char[][] a) {
          char[][] gliderArray = {{' ','*',' '},
                                     {' ','*','*'},
                                     {'*',' ','*'}};

          for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
             gliderArray[i][j] = a[i][j];
          }
        }

        return gliderArray;
       }


    }
```

Comment: **Homework** is a taboo word on SO. Never use the word... **homework.**  Personal project maybe...but homework...never.

Comment: What do you mean by condensing it? What's the problem?